# Изменять начальный цвет

Tags: java, android

Cтолкнулся с новой задачей:

Использовать один цвет для 3-х элементов, делая цвета разными, наложив маску определенно прозрачности(%).

Самое быстрое что пришло в голову это в качестве маски накладывать layout как "плёнкой", примерно так делает дизайнер, берёт один цвет и накладывает на него "черный фон" c opacity 5% для 2-го элемента, и 8 % для 3-го элемента.

Но такой способ не совсем подходит так как элемент на который будем накладывать маску имеет закругленные углы где под ним уже другой фон, соответственно в места где находятся углы элемента, у фона также будет меняться цвет.

Пробовал менять саму прозрачность для элементов(с помощью setAlpha()), но не получаю конкретные цвета.
Начальный цвет: #7099b3;
Требуемые значения:
2-ой элемент: #738ab1
3-ий элемент: #757baf

Может кто то видит альтернативу для данной задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поинтересоваться почему не подходит вариант с наложением layout'a?

Ведь вы можете отрисовать layout с закругленными углами c помощью `shape`.
Тем самым фон не будет никак меняться и вы получите желаемый результат для того или иного элемента.

Пример `.xml`:

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        <corners android:radius="20.0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Где `corners` углы, там уже устанавливаете необходимые вам.

**UPD**:

Чтобы установить цвету прозрачность вставьте [нужные цифры](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39128318/6387618) для определенного % прозрачности.

Примерно это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<solid android:color="#0D000000" />
```

Также можно устанавливать прозрачность для той или иной `view` следующим образом:

```
view.getBackground().setAlpha(30);
```

В метод `setAlpha()` устанавливаешь необходимый атрибут прозрачности, где 0 это полностью прозрачный, а 255 полностью непрозрачный.

Comment: А как возможно проставить здесь прозрачность для данного элемента?